# How to insert into Visual Studio Database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I can't get my code to insert data into Visual Studio database. There are no error and the aspx page run fine but the data is not being write. Here is my code:

```
Dim strConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Project1ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim drCart As SqlDataReader
    Dim strSQLStatement As String
    Dim cmdSQL As SqlCommand
    strSQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM OrderHead"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
    cmdSQL = New SqlCommand(strSQLStatement, conn)
    conn.Open()
    drCart = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader()

    Dim ExpCard = CMonth.Text + CYear.Text
    Dim Fname = FristTxt.Text
    Dim Lname = LastTxt.Text
    Dim Address1 = AddTxt1.Text
    Dim Address2 = AddTxt2.Text
    Dim City = CityTxt.Text
    Dim State = StateDList.Text
    Dim ZipCode = ZipTxt.Text
    Dim PhoneNum = NumTxt.Text
    Dim CreditNum = CNumber.Text
    Dim CreditType = CtypeList.Text

    If drCart.Read() Then

        Dim strSQLStatement2 = "Insert into OrderHead (FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, City, State, Zip, PhoneNumber, CreditCard, CreditType, ExpDate, StreetAddress2) VALUES (" & Trim(Fname) &
            ", " & Trim(Lname) & ", " & Trim(Address1) & ", " & Trim(City) & ", " & Trim(State) &
            ", " & CInt(ZipCode) & ", " & CInt(PhoneNum) & ", " & CInt(CreditNum) & ", " & Trim(CreditType) &
            ", " & CInt(ExpCard) & ", " & Trim(Address2) & "')"
        Dim conn2 As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
        conn2.Open()
        Dim cmdSQL2 = New SqlCommand(strSQLStatement2, conn2)
        drCart = cmdSQL2.ExecuteReader()
        conn2.Close()
    End If
```

I be greatly appreciated if you can point out my error.

Comment: Dont use ExecuteReader to INSERT data; dont concat SQL, use Parameters and for the sake of all that is holy, dont store credit card numbers unencrypted (if at all) and certainly not as Ints.  And dispose of your DB objects

Answer (score 0):

As Plutonix says:  ExecuteReader is for reading the results of a SELECT query a row at a time.  You want [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) to run an INSERT query.

Also, NEVER use concatenation to build a query with user input.  In some cases you might find it useful to build queries from pre-defined strings, but with random input, a person with bad intentions could wipe out your entire database with the right input.  Use [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)!!